# Alpine Docker CMD not starting crond as expected

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

```
CMD php-fpm -D && nginx -g "daemon off;" && crond -f
```

Container only starts php-fpm and nginx, it doesn't start the crond. I am using Alpine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have php-fpm running as a daemon but you turn it off for nginx. Why is that?

Comment: This is for the development only. Main thing is, crond is not able to start automatically. PHP-FPM and NGinx running fine.

Comment: Please attach the whole source code of Dockerfile

Comment: please open this https://gist.github.com/AndrewAyush/bad370b646d153ca8382b354f26f4ef3

Comment: If you run the above gist in a Dockerfile, build it, create a container, and login into that container and run ps it will show PHP fpm and nginx are running but not crond. if you just run crond manually, it will show in ps as well.

Comment: Can you run PHP, Nginx, and cron in three separate containers?  That'd be a much more typical Docker style.  (If PHP-FPM accidentally exits, nothing will notice; if the cron daemon accidentally exits, it will take the other two services with it.)